# Best way to add data elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am posting data so I can search it later in elastic search.

I am posting it like this:

```
POST https://localhost:9200/superheroes/_doc/27
```

body:

```
{
    "name": "Flash",
    "super_power": "Super Speed"
}
```

This is automatically stored on a `_source` object... but I read [the _source field itself is not indexed (and thus is not searchable)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) online, and the entire purpose of this application is quick search by value... like if I wanna know which superheroes have super speed and I write super speed on the search bar.

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you are right about the `_source` field, but if you don't define the mapping for your fields, Elasticsearch generates the default mapping with default param for these fields . You can read more about the [mapping param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-params.html) and in your case, if you want field to be searchable it needs to be the part of the inverted index and this is controlled by the [index param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html).

You can override the value of these params by defining your own mapping(recommended otherwise Elasticsearch will guess the field type based on the first data you index in a field).

**Hope this helps and clears your doubt, in short if you are not defining your mapping, your `text` data is searchable by default.**